# Editing a WordPress Header File

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make edits to my header, so I can add things such as:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

The problem is that I can't find the header file to actually add that to.

The website I am working on is academyofperformancearts.com if that helps.

Comment: The header-file is normally in the wp-contents/<theme-name-here>-folder, isn't it? Something like that, anyway.

Comment: what theme are you using and is it a child theme?

Comment: Junkfoodjunkie is right. Or you can log in the WordPress and go to appearance/editor. You have to have that theme selected. If your child theme is selected then you have to switch to main and then go to appearance/editor.

Comment: junkfoodjunkie Yeah I read it should be there but there doesn't seem to be anything I can download and add tags to. WEBjuju I'm using cherry theme (http://www.templatemonster.com/free-cherry-wordpress-theme.html#gref) with child theme "theme54793" (http://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/54793.html#gref). Valius79 and upon switching to the main theme will it screw up what I have on the website now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, you could just install a plugin that adds the header you need.  For instance [Security Headers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/security-headers/) can

> exposes controls for:

- HSTS (Strict-Transport-Security)
- HPKP (Public-Key-Pins)
- Disabling content sniffing (X-Content-Type-Options)
- XSS protection (X-XSS-Protection)
- Clickjacking mitigation (X-Frame-Options in main site)

Comment: Ahh, that's true. I'll look into that plugin as well as others like it. Thanks!